# terraform 12 for each

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform

I'm trying to create listener rules on alb with defined IP addresses as the allowed ones to hit the **/app** target.

However according to alb listener rules the only allowed values to define per rule is 5. The format of my rule is this:

- Http request method is **POST**
- Path is **/app**
- Host is **my-app.domain.net**
- Source IP is **11.11.11.11/24** OR **12.12.12.12/24**

The values in **BOLD** font above are already  values, however I still need to add 4 more IP's to allow on the ALB listener rule. So to add the other 4 IPs I need to create 2nd  listener rule with this added:

- Http request method is **POST**
- Path is **/app**
- Host is **my-app.domain.net**
- Source IP is **13.13.13.13/24** OR **14.14.14.14/24**

and the 3rd last rule

- Http request method is **POST**
- Path is **/app**
- Host is **my-app.domain.net**
- Source IP is **16.16.16.16/24** OR **16.16.16.16/24**

**QUESTION:** With this tfvar variable I'm using, how can I perform **for-each** logic on the defined source_ip condition on my **aws_alb_listener_rule**? I prefer to add 2 IP's per rule

```
variable.tfvars

IP_ADDRESS = [
 "11.11.11.11/24", 
 "12.12.12.12/24", 
 "13.13.13.13/24",
 "14.14.14.14/24",
 "15.15.15.15/24",
 "16.16.16.16/24"
]
```

how may I add for-each on source_ip condition of aws_alb_listener_rule?

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "target" {
  listener_arn = data.aws_alb_listener.listener.arn


  action {
    target_group_arn = var.target_arn
    type             = "forward"
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/app"]
    }
  }

  condition {
    http_request_method {
      values = ["POST"]
    }
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["my-app.domain.net"]
    }
  }
  condition {
    source_ip {
      values = var.IP_ADDRESS
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You should consider using a regional WAF for this instead of embedding this logic into your ALB listener rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved, I just decided to have 1 IP per listener-rule. Since the IP Address from the list are 6 then this terraform code will also deploy 6 times via count(loop). I used the code below

```
variable "ip_addresses" {
  type = list
}


locals {
  ip_address_chunks = chunklist(var.ip_addresses, 1)
}

resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "target" {
  count = length(var.ip_addresses)

  listener_arn = data.aws_alb_listener.listener.arn

  action {
    target_group_arn = var.target_arn
    type             = "forward"
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/app"]
    }
  }
  condition {
    http_request_method {
      values = ["POST"]
    }
  }
  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["my-app.domain.net"]
    }
  }
  condition {
    source_ip {
      values = local.ip_address_chunks[count.index]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a rare use-case for Terraform's [`chunklist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/chunklist.html) function, which takes a list and returns a list of lists with the inner lists containing no more than a given number of elements.

```
variable "ip_addresses" {
  type = list(string)
}

locals {
  # ALB listener rules allow at most five values per rule.
  # We're going to specify two per rule, which is within that limit.
  ip_address_chunks = chunklist(var.ip_addresses, 2)
}

resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "target" {
  count = local.ip_address_chunks

  listener_arn = data.aws_alb_listener.listener.arn

  action {
    target_group_arn = var.target_arn
    type             = "forward"
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/app"]
    }
  }
  condition {
    http_request_method {
      values = ["POST"]
    }
  }
  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["my-app.domain.net"]
    }
  }
  condition {
    source_ip {
      values = local.ip_address_chunks[count.index]
    }
  }
}
```

A caveat with the above is what will happen if the value of `var.ip_addresses` changes while listener rules already exist. Let's start with the original list of IP addresses you gave in your question:

- `["11.11.11.11/24", "12.12.12.12/24", "13.13.13.13/24", "14.14.14.14/24", "15.15.15.15/24", "16.16.16.16/24"]`

On initial creation, Terraform would create the following instances of `aws_alb_listener-rule.target`:

- `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[0]` with `["11.11.11.11/24", "12.12.12.12/24"]`
- `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[1]` with `["13.13.13.13/24", "14.14.14.14/24"]`
- `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[2]` with `["15.15.15.15/24", "16.16.16.16/24"]`

If you were to remove `13.13.13.13/24` from the list and re-plan, you'll see Terraform wanting to change the rules to the following:

- `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[0]` with `["11.11.11.11/24", "12.12.12.12/24"]`
- `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[1]` with `["14.14.14.14/24", "15.15.15.15/24"]`
- `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[2]` with `["16.16.16.16/24"]`

This would cause an update to both `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[1]` *and* `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[2]`, to re-allocate the new list of IP addresses across the rules.

Because each of those two changes is a separate remote API call it's worth considering what happens if `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[2]` gets updated first (`15.15.15.15/24` would temporarily be in no rules at all) and if `aws_alb_listener-rule.target[1]` gets updated first (`15.15.15.15/24` would temporarily be specified in two rules).

Comment: Martin Atkins - I forgot to mention the aws_alb_listener_rule should be deployed 3 times due to it needs to have 3 separate rules. I see you are right

Comment: Hi Martin, after I tried to copy your suggested code, I'm getting this error = 
"count = local.ip_address_chunks" is there anything I need to modify?

Answer (score -1):

You can use null__resource as an implemention for loops in terraform. This is not intuitive as for / foreach loops in programming languages.

Example of a null_resource:

```
resource "null_resource" "principals" {
  count = "${length(var.trusted_role_arn)}"
  triggers {
    roles="${element((var.trusted_role_arn), count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Then you can load the 'roles' by:

```
["${null_resource.principals.*.triggers.roles}"]
```

[Full explanation here](https://hub.develeap.com/loops-in-terraform/)